Fast way to Separate Data from Array
I have an int array with some data. This array collects data from a 4-channel device.
The array by device every second fills like this: (data is about 200000 numbers)
int[] data = new data[]{1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,...};
//data[0] received from Channel 0
//data[1] received from Channel 1 
//data[2] received from Channel 2 
//data[3] received from Channel 3
//data[4] received from Channel 0
//data[5] received from Channel 1 
//data[6] received from Channel 2 
//data[7] received from Channel 3
// to end...

and to end. After each second I have to separate the channel's data for processing.
For separating each channel I use this code:
double[] ai1 = new double[data.Length/4];
double[] ai2 = new double[data.Length/4];
double[] ai3 = new double[data.Length/4];
double[] ai4 = new double[data.Length/4];
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length/4; i++)
{
    ai1[i] = data[i * 4 + 0];
    ai2[i] = data[i * 4 + 1];
    ai3[i] = data[i * 4 + 2];
    ai4[i] = data[i * 4 + 3];
}

Is there any fast way to separate this array into four subarrays?
Update:
I use "Parallel.For" and it takes about 0.02ms on my computer.
but if I use simple "for", it takes about 0.001ms!
 double[] ai1 = new double[data.Length / 4];
 double[] ai2 = new double[data.Length / 4];
 double[] ai3 = new double[data.Length / 4];
 double[] ai4 = new double[data.Length / 4];
 Parallel.For(0, data.Length / 4, i =>
 {
     ai1[i] = data[i * 4 + 0];
     ai2[i] = data[i * 4 + 1];
     ai3[i] = data[i * 4 + 2];
     ai4[i] = data[i * 4 + 3];
 });


"is this code efficient enough?" How should we know? Only you know what "fast" means. Having said this you should measure how long it takes to process this data

Most likely you don't have to partition anything yourself. Parallel.ForEach, Parallel.For  and Parallel LINQ automatically partition in-memory data and use separate worker tasks to process the data and collect the results

dear @MakePeaceGreatAgain, you are right. I will measure the process time.

are you aware that you loop every elemnt in your data-array, not just every fourth?

Dear Panagiotis Kanavos, thanks, I will try Parallel.

Remember, if we take one foreach, it uses one thread, depending on your computer speed, faster CPU faster result. When using Parallel Foreach, it tries to initialize multiple threads for it, the initiation process takes time. therefore it is slower.

Can the device be configured to send the data in a different order, say, all channel 1 data, then all channel 2 data...?


is this code efficient enough?

How should we be able to tell? What are your performance requirements / expectations?
The first rule of optimization is to start with measuring. If you have no idea how long your method takes you have no idea if you made any improvements. Profiling your application is also a good idea, so you can compare the cost of this method in relation to everything else. There is probably little point in optimizing a method that is only responsible for 1% of the runtime.
If your method takes 0.001ms, or 1us, there is likely little point in doing any optimization unless it is also called thousands of times each second.
All that said, there is no large inefficiencies in the example code. You could spread out the computation over more cores using something like Parallel.For, but this will only help if you have idle cores available. It also has some overhead, so will only help if you have enough data to work on. You may also need to partition your data manually to reduce overhead of calling the delegate.
A more advanced solution would be to use SIMD. The main idea is to load 4 vectors from your source, then blend these vectors to move all the values between vectors, so each vector only contains values from one channel, and then shuffle the vectors to put the values in the correct order again. Convert AoS to SoA in C using SIMD includes a example of this in C using SSE for 3 separate channels. The advantage of SIMD is better utalization of CPU resources. The downsides is much more complicated code, and that not all CPUs support the same SIMD instructions, so you likely need a fallback.
AoS stands for "Array of Structures", i.e. your original data. While SoA stands for "Structure of Arrays", i.e. what you want.
